# Filtering pandas dataframe based on length of frozenset

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with values as frozensets

df

```
foo
frozenset('A')
frozenset('B','C') and so on
```

Code:

```
df[len(df.foo)>1]
```

The above code should give me rows with at least two elements, right? If not, then how?

Comment: what does your dataframe look like? `print(df)`

Comment: *The above code should give me rows with at least two elements, right? If not, then how?* Why don't you try and find out. If it gives an error edit the question and add that info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Series.str.len`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.len.html) working nice with iterables:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'foo':[frozenset('A'),frozenset(['B','C'])]})
print (df)
      foo
0     (A)
1  (C, B)

df1 = df[df['foo'].str.len() > 1]
#another solution with list comprehension
#df1 = df[[len(x) > 1 for x in df['foo']]]
print (df1)
      foo
1  (C, B)
```